# PayPal Subscription for Recurring Payments in php

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using following code to make a Payment Subscription.

```
$paypalURL = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'; //Test PayPal API URL
$paypalID = ''; //Business Email
$usermail = $idarray->email;
                     <form action="<?php echo $paypalURL; ?>" method="post">
                     <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
                     <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypalID; ?>">

                    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">

                    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->

                     <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value=Elearning - Kurs">
                     <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
                     <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="IN">
                     <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
                     <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
                     <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="1">
                     <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="12">
                     <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">

                    <!-- Specify URLs -->
                     <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='https://contao.netz-garage.de/fehlgeschlagen.html'>
                     <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://contao.netz-garage.de/erfolgreich.html'>
                     <input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='https://contao.netz-garage.de/ipn.php'>

                    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
                     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submitted">
                     <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
                     </form><br><br>
```

I get to the confirm Site but after that I get to the following site:

> failed
>   [image]